# startAnimatingWithImagesInRange reverse

Tags: ios, animation, reverse, apple-watch

I am developing an Apple watch application. In the application I have progress bar with animation. I am using

```
  - (void)startAnimatingWithImagesInRange:(NSRange)imageRange
                                 duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
                              repeatCount:(NSInteger)repeatCount
```

This is fine for increasing progress like 0 to 50. I would like to know is there any way I can reverse this like 50 to 0. I have already tried with minus NSRange length value with no luck.

Thanks

Comment: what is the value of repeatCount

Comment: make it -1 and put initial value as 50

Comment: @vijeesh  making repeatCount to -1 is infinite loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the docs for `WKInterfaceImage` (https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceImage_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKInterfaceImage/startAnimatingWithImagesInRange:duration:repeatCount:), all you have to do is supply a negative value to `duration`.

Comment: @bgiham thanks... i didn't read the documentation properly. :D I though negative value would be in imageRange.

Comment: [imgViewProgressTracker startAnimatingWithImagesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 101) duration:-30 repeatCount:1]; passed the negative duration suggested by @bgilham.